# Jenkins Git, Get all commits in the last Push in Pull Requests

Tags: git, jenkins, commit, pull-request

I have a Job looking for PRs in github and I want to know which folder was changed since the last push, because I need to execute different commands.
I have this command:

```
git diff --quiet --exit-code HEAD~1..HEAD api || echo > api.changed
git diff --quiet --exit-code HEAD~1..HEAD front || echo > front.changed
```

But with this, I only know what changed since the last commit. If my push contains more than one commit, It only will evaluate the last commit.
I know that Jenkins run the job only when detects changes in the PR from the last commit. Also if the job had run and I push againt 2 more commits, I want to know only the changes in that push.

I can't use pipeline for this, so the **when** statement with **changeset** is dismiss.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `git log A..B`

> `..` / `...`
> In git those 2 or 3 dots mean range = between (include and exclude).
> Most common used with `git cherry-pick <start>..<end>`

Steps:

1. Get the last commit - you have it in Jenkins or grab it in your script before the job starts with

   ```sh
   # Get the past SHA1 of the current commit
   git log -1 --pretty=%T
   ```
2. Once the script finish execute the diff command

   ```sh
   # Get the list of commits in range (in this sample its the last 3 commits)
   # In your case it will be the HEAD...<SHA1>

   $ git log HEAD...HEAD~3 --pretty="%T"
   06ae26a709d5b955adc0d760dd9faafcf9905820
   da3e68ae566bba72748843167844d5ffb72d8163
   270d08cd9867423987e1fa28e5b3658394cbe792
   ```

---

> I want to know only the changes in that push.

If you wish to view the content and not the commits themself you can use `whatchanged`

#### `git whatchanged`

Once you what is your referenced commit you can see the list of files which were updated during this time period with the `git whatchanged` command

```
# Print out a list of files which was updated/added between the 2 commits git 
whatchanged <TAG_NAME>...HEAD
```

[image]